# How to adjust parameter of SVM for better training

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, svm, training-data

I am working on a Linear SVM and I am using Opencv with Python, I am trying to adjust the parameters for better training but still not getting the good results, I am feeling that I am going through wrong parameter setting,

```
# Create SVM classifier
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_EPS_SVR)
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
#cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR
svm.setDegree(3)
svm.setGamma(1)
svm.setCoef0(0.0)
svm.setC(0.01)
svm.setNu(0.5)
svm.setP(0.1)
#svm.setClassWeights(0)
```

I am using above parameters and taking lot of help from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp#L311-L322).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd getter better results with searching for the optimal parameter values using [`trainAuto`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d2d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1SVM.html#a533d3d3f950fed3f75be0d8692eeff58). You cannot copy the param values from some other application and expect to get good results on your own data.

When you call say `svm.getType()` you get an int value, for example 100. To understand then the type see [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d1/d2d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1SVM.html), under **Public Types** you find this:

> enum      Types {    C_SVC =100,    NU_SVC =101,    ONE_CLASS =102,
>   EPS_SVR =103,    NU_SVR =104  }

Hence, 100 means `C_SVC`. And for the kernel type you find:

> enum      KernelTypes {    CUSTOM =-1,    LINEAR =0,    POLY =1,    RBF
>   =2,    SIGMOID =3,    CHI2 =4,    INTER =5  }

Then 2 means the RBF kernel yields the best accuracy on your data.

Comment: trainAuto also make the issue at prediction time when we use `hog.setSVMDetector(svm_new)` of `detector size`

Comment: When I try to get type and kernel with `trainAuto`, it shows `print (svm.getType()) #100` print 100 value of Type and
`print (svm.getKernelType()) #2` 2 value for KernelType.